# Getting null is not an Object (evaluating "scratchImagePath.uri"), though i am passing the values?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

```
<ScratchImageView 
                brushSize = {10}
                threshold = {10}
                style={{height: 300, width: 300}}
                onRevealPercentChanged={this.onRevealPercentChanged}
                onRevealed={this.onRrevealPercent=50}
                resizeMode= "cover"
                strokeWidth={20}
                imageScratched={{uri: './scratchReward.jpg'}}
                imagePattern={{uri: './scratchTopLayer.jpg'}}
            />
```

Why do i get null is not an object exception, though passing the values?

Comment: I tried both absolute and relative paths

Comment: Hi, You find any solution. I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `require` like

```
require('./path/to/image.png')
```

So your component code= will be like

```
        <ScratchImageView 
                brushSize = {10}
                threshold = {10}
                style={{height: 300, width: 300}}
                onRevealPercentChanged={this.onRevealPercentChanged}
                onRevealed={this.onRrevealPercent=50}
                resizeMode= "cover"
                strokeWidth={20}
                imageScratched={uri: require('./scratchReward.jpg')}
                imagePattern={uri: require('./scratchTopLayer.jpg')}
            />
```

You can use the relative path here.